# how to use/implement a scroll bar on java

Tags: java

I have a project which requires a signup form and I cannot find a specific answer to my question so sorry if such a question has already been posted.

I trying to find a simple code that can be used to implement/use the scrollbar (not scrollPane) in an internal frame (on a desktop pane)

Comment: Can you share whatever you have tried so far?

Comment: Is scroll-bar supposed to work differently than a scroll-pane ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than using the scrollbar specifically is the scroll pane. it was much easier.

Simple codings for the scroll bar were hard to find.

Watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXz5yDagBBY (no coding )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code with scrollBar

```
public class ScrollBarSample {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            JScrollBar oneJScrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollBar Sample");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(oneJScrollBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.setSize(300, 200);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Then you should consider listening to scrolling events with a `ChangeListener`